# XML / XSL: Need ending tag, yet ending tag is there. Keep getting error

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm doing a timetable xml and xsl, the xsl is apparently wrong and is saying the following error:
Error on line 15 column 9 -
SXXP0003: Error reported by XML parser: The element type "ol" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "< /ol >".

XML code is here: http://textuploader.com/dabkb

The XSL is this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Timetable Wage</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h2>Print the names of all modules on the timetables</h2>
                <ol>
                    <xsl:for-each select="/timetable/module"/>
                        <li><xsl:value-of select="name"/></li>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </ol>


            <h2>Print the names of all modules which have an exam</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Modules with exam</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="/timetable/module/exam/..">
                        <tr>
                            <td><xsl: value-of select="name"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>

            <h2>Print name, day, time, room of all lab classes</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Day</th>
                        <th>Time</th>
                        <th>Room</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="/timetable/module/name|/timetable/module/classes/lab">
                        <tr>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="day"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="time"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="room"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>

            <h2>Print the details of any module which has more than one lecture in a week</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Day</th>
                        <th>Time</th>
                        <th>Room</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="/timetable/module/classes/lecture[@id>0]|//name">
                        <tr>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="day"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="time"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="room"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>

            <h2>Print the day, time and room of all classes which take place in computer labs</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Day</th>
                        <th>Time</th>
                        <th>Room</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="//room[@type='computerLab']/..|//name">
                        <tr>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="day"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="time"/></td>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="room"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>

            <h2>Print the name of all modules which have classes on a Monday</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="//day[text()='Mon']/..|//name">
                        <tr>
                            <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>                    
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Note: I'm not looking for other errors at this time, I'm trying to test it.

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate your XML-level syntax errors in your XSLT...

Change

```
                <xsl:for-each select="/timetable/module"/>
```

to

```
                <xsl:for-each select="/timetable/module">
```

and change

```
                        <td><xsl: value-of select="name"/></td>
```

to

```
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
```

These corrections will just get your XSLT to be well-formed.  ([Your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39896421/xml-xsl-need-ending-tag-yet-ending-tag-is-there-keep-getting-error/39896660#comment67078519_39896421) indicated that you're not looking for further errors at this time.)